# How to assign type specific value on ref generic variable in C#?

Tags: c#

Let's imagine a generic method :

```
public void DoSomething<T>(ref T value) where T : struct
{
  if(value is float)
  {
    value = (T)0.5f;
  }
}
```

This doesn't work. Searching the internet, I found the solution to this is :

```
value = (T)(object) 0.5f;
```

I am just curious, since it's boxing and unboxing the value, isn't it allocating extra memory, which will need to garbage collected? Is there no other better way to assign the float value to the generic variable?

Comment: Type checks inside generics is usually a smell. Here it seems likely that you shouldn't be using generics at all but writing separate methods for each struct type you *do* know how to support. E.g `DoSomething(ref float value)` contains the float specific code, `DoSomething(ref int value)` would contain the int code. No boxing, no code smell.

Comment: Worth noting is that at runtime, this "virtual" overhead disappears when `DoSomething<..>` actually gets jitted. If `T` is `float`, there's a direct assignment with the constant; if `T` is not `float`, the method is empty. That doesn't necessarily make this a good pattern, of course, but you needn't be concerned about memory.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thanks, that's all I was looking for. If there's no extra memory allocation, I am good to go with that.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't necessarily consider what will happen at run time. Your `if` statement will guarantee that, at run time, the line inside the `if` block will never be executed if `T` is not `float` but the compiler doesn't consider that. When it evaluates this line:

```cs
value = (T)0.5f;
```

all it cares about is whether that cast is valid for all `T`. It's not, so the code won't compile. In this case:

```cs
value = (T)(object) 0.5f;
```

the cast from `float` to `object` is valid and the cast from `object` to `T` is valid for all `T` so the code compiles. Note that this code fails to compile for the same reason:

```cs
public void DoSomething<T>(ref T value) where T : struct
{
    if (value is float)
    {
        value = (T)"Hello World";
    }
}
```

while this code does compile for the same reason:

```cs
public void DoSomething<T>(ref T value) where T : struct
{
    if (value is float)
    {
        value = (T)(object)"Hello World";
    }
}
```

Obviously that last snippet would throw an exception at run time but, as I said, the compiler doesn't consider all the potential execution paths and which ones can and can't happen at run time. Casting `string` as `T` is not valid while casting `string` as `object` and `object` as `T` both are.

Comment: I'd be interested to know why someone chose to down-vote this. If I've done something wrong then I'd like to know what it is so that I can correct it, or it may be a chance to correct your own faulty thinking.

Comment: While I did not down-vote, I can hazard that it was because your answer is not something the question asked about. The question was whether there are better ways to do it, not why the direct cast doesn't work.